# PhpMailer: how to pass array through from phpmailer to template

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to pass arrays coming from a database and loop them in the email template using phpMailer.
Using following script I can pass single variables and print them in the template:

```
$message = file_get_contents('template.php');
$message = str_replace('%lname%', $lname, $message);

// Setup PHPMailer
   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->IsSMTP();

  $mail->SetFrom('info@mywebsite.com','mywebsite.com'); 
  $mail->AddAddress('r.user@gmail.com');


  $mail->Subject = 'New message'; 
  $mail->MsgHTML($message);

  if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  }
```

Now I would like to pass arrays coming from a database to the related template.

How can I pass them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple render function

```
function render($template, $data )
{
    extract($data);
    ob_start();
    include( $template  );
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $content;
}

$body = render(__DIR__.'/template.php' , ['first' => 'This is first line' , 'second' => 'this is second line']);
```

template.php

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><?=$first ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?=$second ?></td>
</tr>
```

Then send message

```
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
        $mail->setFrom( $from, 'Mailer');
        $mail->addAddress($to);
        $mail->isHTML(true);

        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $body;

        $mail->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just repeat that process for as many tags as you want, but note that there are several search & replace functions in PHP like [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) that accept arrays so you can do many at once.

If you want to get more sophisticated, you can use a template engine like Smarty or Twig.

Overall this has nothing to do with PHPMailer - it will just send whatever you generate, it's an entirely separate thing.